# Deleting JComponents/JTextFields from JPanel whose reference are stored in ArrayList<JTextField>

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jpanel, jcomponent

```
ArrayList<JTextField> arrayFinal; /*
                                     LIKE global variable
                     Have initialize part, for alloc memory for arayFinal.
                      */
```

Also have part where add to panel, `JTextFields` from `arrayFinal`. And now in this function, can't remove from panel that elements...

```
public void arrayFinalErase(JPanel panel){

        for ( JTextField text : arrayFinal){
            panel.remove(text);
        }
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();

        /*
         *  Also tried
         *  panel.remove(arrayFinal.get(......)); 
         *  but also doesn't work
         */
    }
```

**EDIT, insert full code:**

```
JButton dodajButton = new JButton("Dodaj");
    dodajButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            System.out.println("--------\n TEXT: " + arrayFinal.get(0).getText() );
            panel.remove(arrayFinal.get(0));

            panel.revalidate();
            panel.repaint();

        }
    });
    dodajButton.setBounds(851, 35, 89, 23);
    panel.add(dodajButton);

    JButton sacuvajButton = new JButton("Sacuvaj");
    sacuvajButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try {
                sacuvajArray();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    sacuvajButton.setBounds(851, 7, 89, 23);
    panel.add(sacuvajButton);



    scrollPane.setBounds(10, 11, 969, 400 );
    scrollPane.setBackground(Color.green);

    contentPane.add(scrollPane);


    countRows = count(ID);
    if ( countRows!= 0){
        setBeginning();

        for( ArrayList<JTextField> tmp : list){
            textDrawWithArray(tmp, panel);
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("dadada");
        textDrawDefault(panel);
        finalDraw(panel);

    }



}

public int count(int ID) throws SQLException{

    String sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS total FROM tabelle_1 WHERE ID = " + ID + ";";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    return rs.getInt(1);
}

public void setBeginning() throws SQLException{


    String sql = "SELECT * FROM tabelle_1 WHERE ID =" + ID + ";";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


    if ( rs.next()){

        ArrayList<JTextField> tmp;
        do{
            tmp = arrayAllocJTextField();

            tmp.add(textAlloc(rs.getString("datum")));
            tmp.add(textAlloc(Double.toString(rs.getDouble("cena"))));
            tmp.add(textAlloc(Double.toString(rs.getDouble("brojLekcija"))));
            tmp.add(textAlloc(Double.toString(rs.getDouble("total"))));
            tmp.add(textAlloc(rs.getString("opisRadnje")));
            tmp.add(textAlloc(rs.getString("cena_1")));
            tmp.add(textAlloc(rs.getString("brojLekcija_1")));
            tmp.add(textAlloc(rs.getString("total_1")));

            list.add(tmp);  




        }while(rs.next());

    }


    rs.close();

}

public ArrayList<String> arrayAllocString(){
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}

public ArrayList<JTextField> arrayAllocJTextField(){
    return new ArrayList<JTextField>();
}

public JTextField textAlloc(String text){
    return new JTextField(text);
}

public void textDrawWithArray(ArrayList<JTextField> array, JPanel panel){

    JTextField textTemp;


    int i = 1;
    for( JTextField text : array){

        if ( i == 1){

            textTemp = textAlloc(Integer.toString(redniBroj));
            textTemp.setColumns(10);
            textTemp.setBounds(x_pos[0], y_pos, x_duz[0], y_duz);   
            textTemp.setEditable(false);

            panel.add(textTemp);
            redniBroj++;
        }

        textTemp = textAlloc(text.getText());
        textTemp.setColumns(10);
        textTemp.setBounds(x_pos[i], y_pos, x_duz[i], y_duz);

        panel.add(textTemp);
        i++;
    }

    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();
    y_pos += 30;
}

public void textDrawDefault(JPanel panel){

    JTextField textTemp;
    ArrayList<JTextField> tmp = arrayAllocJTextField();

    for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++){

        if ( i == 0){
            textTemp = textAlloc(Integer.toString(redniBroj));
            textTemp.setColumns(10);
            textTemp.setBounds(x_pos[i], y_pos, x_duz[i], y_duz);
            textTemp.setEditable(false);

            panel.add(textTemp);
            redniBroj++;

            continue;
        }else if ( i == 4 || i == 8){
            textTemp = textAlloc("");
            textTemp.setEditable(false);
            textTemp.setColumns(10);
            textTemp.setBounds(x_pos[i], y_pos, x_duz[i], y_duz);

            tmp.add(textTemp);

            if ( i == 4){
            textTemp.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

                @Override
                public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
                        if ( !tmp.get(1).getText().equals("") && !tmp.get(2).getText().equals("")){
                        double a = Double.parseDouble(tmp.get(1).getText());
                        double b = Double.parseDouble(tmp.get(2).getText());

                        tmp.get(3).setText("" + (a*b));
                        }


                }

                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });

            }else{
                textTemp.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {

                        if ( !tmp.get(5).getText().equals("") && !tmp.get(6).getText().equals("")){
                                double a = Double.parseDouble(tmp.get(5).getText());
                                double b = Double.parseDouble(tmp.get(6).getText());

                                tmp.get(7).setText("" + (a*b));
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                });
            }

            panel.add(textTemp);
            continue;

        }

        textTemp = textAlloc("");
        textTemp.setColumns(10);
        textTemp.setBounds(x_pos[i], y_pos, x_duz[i], y_duz);
        textTemp.setText("");

        panel.add(textTemp);
        tmp.add(textTemp);

    }

    list.add(tmp);
    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();
    y_pos += 30;
    System.out.println("cechk default");

}


public void sacuvajArray() throws SQLException{

    String[] textBase = new String[8];

    String sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM tabelle_1 WHERE ID = "+ ID + ";";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sqlDelete);

    String sqlInsert;

    int i = 0;
    for(ArrayList<JTextField> arrayChild : list){

        i= 0;

        for( JTextField text : arrayChild){
            textBase[i++] = text.getText();

        }
        sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO tabelle_1 (ID, datum, cena, brojLekcija, total, opisRadnje, cena_1, brojLekcija_1, total_1)   VALUES(" 
                + ID + ","
                + "'" + textBase[0] + "',"
                + "'" + textBase[1] + "',"
                + "'" + textBase[2] + "',"
                + "'" + textBase[3] + "',"
                + "'" + textBase[4] + "',"
                + "'" + textBase[5] + "',"
                + "'" + textBase[6] + "',"
                + "'" + textBase[7] + "');";

        stmt.executeUpdate(sqlInsert);

    }

}

public void finalDraw(JPanel panel){

    double brojLekcija=0.0;
    double total= 0.0;

    double cena_1=0.0;
    double brojLekcija_1=0.0;
    double total_1= 0.0;
    int i = 0, y=0;

    for( ArrayList<JTextField> tmp : list){
        i=0;
        for( JTextField textField : tmp){

            if ( i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 4){
                i++;
                continue;
            }


            String text = textField.getText();
            if ( text.equals("")){

                i++;
                continue;
            }

            switch(i){
            case 2:
                brojLekcija += Double.parseDouble(text);
                break;
            case 3:
                total += Double.parseDouble(text);
                break;
            case 5:
                cena_1 += Double.parseDouble(text);
                break;
            case 6:
                brojLekcija_1 += Double.parseDouble(text);
                break;
            case 7:
                total_1 += Double.parseDouble(text);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("ERROR!!");
                break;
            }

            i++;

        }
        System.out.println("-----------------");
    }

    arrayFinal.add(textAlloc("Total"));
    arrayFinal.add(textAlloc(""));
    arrayFinal.add(textAlloc(Double.toString(brojLekcija)));
    arrayFinal.add(textAlloc(Double.toString(total)));
    arrayFinal.add(textAlloc(""));
    arrayFinal.add(textAlloc(Double.toString(cena_1)));
    arrayFinal.add(textAlloc(Double.toString(brojLekcija_1)));
    arrayFinal.add(textAlloc(Double.toString(total_1)));

    textDrawWithArray(arrayFinal, panel);
    System.out.println("OKE JE");

}

public void arrayFinalErase(JPanel panel){

    for ( JTextField text : arrayFinal){
        panel.remove(text);
    }
    panel.revalidate();
    panel.repaint();

    /*
     *  Also tried
     *  panel.remove(arrayFinal.get(......)); 
     *  but also doesn't work
     */

    y_pos -= 30;
}
```

}

Comment: You're going to have to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run.

Comment: Done. Look at addActionListener for dodajButton. It print text, but do not remove from panel.

Comment: is your arrayFinal ArrayList perhaps empty?

Comment: No, i checked it with this line:
System.out.println("--------\n TEXT: " + arrayFinal.get(0).getText() );

Comment: Found influence. Ty guys....

Comment: Could you tell us, what has caused the problem?

Comment: Wrong allocation in textDrawWithArray function

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class FrameExample extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<JTextField> textfieldGroup;

    public FrameExample() {
        setSize(800, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        textfieldGroup = new ArrayList<>();

        init();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        arrayFinalErase();
    }

    private void init() {
        for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            textfieldGroup.add(new JTextField(index));
            add(textfieldGroup.get(index));
        }
        JButton removeAllTextfields = new JButton("remove");
        add(removeAllTextfields);
        removeAllTextfields.addActionListener(this);
    }

    private void arrayFinalErase() {

        for (JTextField text : textfieldGroup) {
            remove(text);
        }
        revalidate();
        repaint();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FrameExample();
    }

}
```

Is your list of TextFields perhaps empty?

Comment: I tried also, on separate program just that section, and it works. But i chceck my program, and found no influence on arrayFinal

Comment: done. Look addActionListener for dodajButton. It print text, but do not remove from panel.